# как сделать так чтобы трек проигрывался сразу на сайте без загрузки на само устройство юзера, чтобы проигрывался сразу в приложении?

Tags: javascript, node.js, expo

Всем привет! У меня появилась проблемка, хочу сделать приложение на Expo.dev в котором можно будет проигрывать записи моих медитаций без их установки (что то типа Spotify или Deezer). Думала о том чтобы сделать ДБ с которой можно сразу проигрывать. Нужна помощь в доведении этой мысли Использую Javascript(React, Expo) для фронта

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нужен способ загрузки треков на сайт и их проигрывания без скачивания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1428934/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Для того, чтобы слушать прямо на сайте, нужен визуальный плеер. Не знаю, можно ли и как его сделать на Expo.dev, но на обычном HTML + JavaScript для этого есть широкая возможность.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший плеер для прослушивания аудио на сайте можно сделать на HTML + Javascript таким образом:

```js
audio.onloadedmetadata = _ => showTime();
range.onchange = _ => audio.currentTime = range.value / 100 * audio.duration;
audio.ontimeupdate = _ => {
    range.value = audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100;
    showTime();
}
playpause.onclick = _ => {
    if(audio.paused){
        audio.play();
        playpause.innerText = ' pause ';
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        playpause.textContent = ' play ';
    }
}
function showTime(){time.innerText = formatingTime(audio.currentTime) + '/' + formatingTime(audio.duration)};
function formatingTime(time){
    let s = Math.floor(time % 60);
    return Math.floor(time / 60) + ':' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s);
}
```

```html
<audio id=audio src='https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/sound.mp3'></audio>
<input id=range type=range value=0 /><br /><br />
<button id=playpause style='cursor: pointer'> play </button>
<pre id=time></pre>
```

В роде, можно только слушать, но на самом деле во время прослушивания аудиофайл уже находится на компьютере. Так же не трудно его скачать глянув на исходный код страницы. (плеера)

Или может неважно на счёт скачивания, а главное, чтобы слушать на сайте? Тогда есть проще вариант:

```html
<audio id=audio src='https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/sound.mp3' controls></audio>
```